# MYSQL 8.0.26 using CPU upto 300-400%

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu-20.04, mysql-slow-query-log

See my processes screenshots

[image: Process list via htop]

I have ubuntu server 20.0 having following VPS configuration

4 vCPU Cores

8 GB RAM

50 GB NVMe

I am also attaching my mysqld.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld]
#sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
# pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# port      = 3306
# datadir   = /var/lib/mysql


# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
# tmpdir        = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 1536M
# max_allowed_packet    = 64M
# thread_stack      = 256K

# thread_cache_size       = -1

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

# max_connections        = 151

# table_open_cache       = 4000

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
#
# Log all queries
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
# general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log      = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 5
log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
# server-id     = 1
# log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
# binlog_do_db      = include_database_name
# binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name
```

I tried to increase key buffer size, I also optimised many number of slow queries by enabling slow query log.

Though it keep using high CPU.

Can I anyone face any such issue?

here is my INNODB configuration:

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb%';
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value                  |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                 | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm             | 10                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index               | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts         | 8                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay          | 150000                 |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval            | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock               | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                     | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment              | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                 | 2                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size            | 134217728              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown      | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct              | 25                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename              | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file          | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances             | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort            | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup       | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 134217728              |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size            | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                  | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                | crc32                  |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled             | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                 | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max           | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets               | 5000                   |
| innodb_data_file_path                    | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                     |                        |
| innodb_deadlock_detect                   | ON                     |
| innodb_dedicated_server                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_default_row_format                | dynamic                |
| innodb_directories                       |                        |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache           | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                       | ON                     |
| innodb_doublewrite_batch_size            | 0                      |
| innodb_doublewrite_dir                   |                        |
| innodb_doublewrite_files                 | 2                      |
| innodb_doublewrite_pages                 | 4                      |
| innodb_extend_and_initialize             | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                     | 1                      |
| innodb_file_per_table                    | ON                     |
| innodb_fill_factor                       | 100                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout              | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                      | fsync                  |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                   | 0                      |
| innodb_flush_sync                        | ON                     |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted              | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                    | 0                      |
| innodb_fsync_threshold                   | 0                      |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                        |
| innodb_idle_flush_pct                    | 100                    |
| innodb_io_capacity                       | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                   | 2000                   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                 | 50                     |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                   | 16777216               |
| innodb_log_checksums                     | ON                     |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages              | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                     | 50331648               |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                | ./                     |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm              | 80                     |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm              | 50                     |
| innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm       | 400                    |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size              | 8192                   |
| innodb_log_writer_threads                | ON                     |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                    | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct               | 90.000000              |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm           | 10.000000              |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                     | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay               | 0                      |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                 | 1073741824             |
| innodb_monitor_disable                   |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                 |                        |
| innodb_numa_interleave                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                    | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                   | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size         | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                        | 4000                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only            | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_cleaners                     | 1                      |
| innodb_page_size                         | 16384                  |
| innodb_parallel_read_threads             | 4                      |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_print_ddl_logs                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                  | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency     | 128                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                     | 4                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold              | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                   | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                         | OFF                    |
| innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs             |                        |
| innodb_redo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                 | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout               | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                 | 128                    |
| innodb_segment_reserve_factor            | 12.500000              |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                   | 6                      |
| innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier        | 50                     |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                 | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked       | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                      | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages     | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages      | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                       | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                   | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                   | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                       | ON                     |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path               | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend  |
| innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir              | ./#innodb_temp/        |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                | 10000                  |
| innodb_tmpdir                            |                        |
| innodb_undo_directory                    | ./                     |
| innodb_undo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate                 | ON                     |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                  | 2                      |
| innodb_use_fdatasync                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_native_aio                    | ON                     |
| innodb_validate_tablespace_paths         | ON                     |
| innodb_version                           | 8.0.26                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads                  | 4                      |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
148 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Which Engine are you using? INNODB ? Please add the innodb config

Comment: @BerndBuffen I updated my question with the INNODB configuration.

Comment: Consider posting last 50 lines of your slow query log and someone may suggest indexes needed for specific queries to reduce CPU busy.      Divide CPU% by #CPU's for avg % busy overall.  When it is 300 / 4 your are averaging 75% busy over all cpu's.

Comment: @ChiragLukhi I am back in my office for the remainder of the week.  Skype works well.  Thanks

Comment: @BerndBuffen do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to use more of NVME capacity
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=10000  # from 150000 for 1 second vs 15 when busy
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0.00001  # from 10.00 to expedite pre-flushing
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0.00001  # from 90.0 percent tolerated dirty pages
```

View profile for contact info and free Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: @Chirag Lukhi  Have you had time to try the 4 suggestions above?  Your perception of results after 7 days of uptime?

Answer (score 0):

Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70$ of *available* RAM.

That will speed up certain things, but not necessarily the CPU.

For that, we need to see your slow queries.

Comment: are you saying 70% of RAM right?

Comment: @ChiragLukhi - for 8GB of RAM and no big apps other than MySQL, 5G would be good.

Comment: Got it. I will check @Rick